# What is request and leave in Clash of Clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans, terminology

What does *request and leave* mean with respect to Supercell's *clash of clans* ?

I have seen too many clan description as request and leave!

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, the objective of the members of those clan with 'Req and Leave' (or 'Req and GTFO') is to gain exp/complete the achievement (the one which requires a number of Clan troop donating) for gems.

It's just for the decorations unlocked through leveling/for the achievement since level in COC doesn't affect War/Farming.

Answer (score 2):

**Request** is to request for troops using the "Request Troops" option which can be selected after tapping on your clan castle.
*Some clans impose restrictions and rules on troop requests as there are many people out there who clan hop or repeatedly ask for troops without giving anything in return.*

**Leave** is to pretty much leave a clan, which is the big red button in the clan information screen.
*Most clans want active players so that they can win wars. It is frowned upon when leaving a clan half-way through a war as it means two less attacks for your clan.*